# Softlayer API: Account destroy?

Tags: api, account, destroy, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Now I'm developing a project about softlayer api, I create a child account by SoftLayer_Brand::createCustomerAccount. Then I wan't to destroy the child account by softlayer api. Is there certain method to destroy? Or make the account does not work by softlayer api?

regards~

Comment: Are you sure it's _possible_ to destroy an account? They may be permanent.

Comment: yes, I wan't to permanent destroy the customer account. Not the BAP account. Do you know about the method?

Answer (score 1):

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand there you can find all the available methods for brands, I am afraid you cannot cancel an account that taks only can be performed by softlayer employee, so if you want to cancel it, you need to submit a ticket and ask about that.