# What's the best way to clean up SoftLayer accounts?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We've been testing our product as as part of the testing we had to internally create a bunch of SoftLayer accounts under a master brand.  What is the best way to close out or delete or remove these accounts?

I was looking at the SoftLayer APIs like Account and Brand and I don't see any Delete/Remove type of APIs.

What SoftLayer APIs can I use so go through each account, cancel all devices and delete the account?  Or at least disable the account?  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This was answered here [Softlayer API: Account destroy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836098/softlayer-api-account-destroy)

You need to submit a ticket in order to delete/inactive the accounts and cancel all devices on them because these tasks only can be performed by a SoftLayer employee.

And if you want to know how to cancel different devices individually through the SoftLayer API, you can review posts which were previously asked here [stackoverflow softlayer cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsoftlayer%5D%20cancel)